# Facing issue with Broadcast video through Vonage (tokbox)

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, tokbox

I am facing issue when i try to broadcast my video in

When I use **'startVideo'** its working fine for me.
But my **'connectVideo'** giving me issue, I have pasted code below. I have attached error screenshot also.
In my first function **'startVideo'** I wrote code to start video its taking my webcam video, through second function **'connectVideo'** i just want share/broadcast my video with my user.

```
    <?php
    
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    
            use OpenTok\OpenTok;
            use OpenTok\MediaMode;
            use OpenTok\ArchiveMode;
            use OpenTok\Role;
            use OpenTok\Session;
            use OpenTok\Broadcast;
            use OpenTok\Layout;
            
    class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
        
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();      
            
            
        }
       
       
        public function index()
        
        {
            $this->load->view('welcome_message');
        }
        
        public function startVideo()
        {   
            
            $opentok = new OpenTok($this->config->item('opentok_key'), $this->config->item('opentok_secret'));
             
            $sessionOptions = array(
            'archiveMode' => ArchiveMode::ALWAYS,
            'mediaMode'   => MediaMode::ROUTED
        );
    
           $session    = $opentok->createSession($sessionOptions);
           $iSessionId = $session->getSessionId();
            
           date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); 
           $created_date  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
            
            $data = array(
                'apiKey'    => $this->config->item('opentok_key'),
                'sessionId' => $iSessionId,
                'token'     => $session->generateToken(),
                'created_date' => $created_date
            );
    
            
            $archiveOptions = array(
                'name' => 'Important Presentation',     // default: null
                'hasAudio' => true,                     // default: true
                'hasVideo' => true,                     // default: true
               // 'outputMode' => OutputMode::COMPOSED, // default: OutputMode::COMPOSED
                'resolution' => '1280x720'              // default: '640x480'
            );
            
            $this->load->view('video_11', $data);       
        }
    
    
        public function connectVideo()    // connect to a session
        {               
            $opentok = new OpenTok($this->config->item('opentok_key'), $this->config->item('opentok_secret'));
            
        $session = $opentok->createSession();
        
        $sessionOptions = array(
            'archiveMode'  => ArchiveMode::ALWAYS,
            'mediaMode'    => MediaMode::ROUTED
        );
        
        
           $session    = $opentok->createSession($sessionOptions);
           $sessionId  = $session->getSessionId();
           
           $options = array(
            'layout' => Layout::getBestFit(),
            'maxDuration' => 5400,
            'resolution' => '1280x720'
            );
           
           $broadcast = $opentok->startBroadcast($sessionId, $options);
          
    
            // Store the broadcast ID in the database for later use
            $broadcastId = $broadcast->id;
            
            $token   = 'T1==T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD00NjQ5MTcwMiZzaWc9Y2MxYzkxYzNmYTkzNmNiNmQ0NDZiNWEzNzVhYjExYTliYTZkOTdlYzpzZXNzaW9uX2lkPTFfTVg0ME5qUTVNVGN3TW41LU1UWXhOVE00TXpJMU16WXdPWDVIWjB0WVp6SlJWRlJhVUV4c2FrczVOa0ZOZGk5SUwwOS1RWDQmY3JlYXRlX3RpbWU9MTYxNTM4MzI1MyZyb2xlPXB1Ymxpc2hlciZub25jZT0xNjE1MzgzMjUzLjY5ODUxOTY3MzAxNjU4';
            
            $data    = array(
                'apiKey' => $this->config->item('opentok_key'),
                'sessionId' => $session,
                'token' => $token   
            );
            
            $this->load->view('video_22', $data);       
        }   
    
        
        
        
    }


[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1qBY.png
```